# URLencoding, Extra data that isn't supposed to be there

Tags: php, html, url, curl, encoding

getURL

```
http://www.example.com/retro-briefcase-messenger-bag-3380
```

Encoded echo

```
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=xxx&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com%2Fretro-briefcase-messenger-bag-3380%0A%3Cbr%3E
```

Curl Code

```
   $curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here

$encodedurl = urlencode($getUrl);

echo "CURL START";
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=xxx&longUrl='.$encodedurl,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0'
));
```

If you realise there seem to be an addtional info behind 3380 which is %0A%3Cbr%3E which I believe represent 
 a tag.

I did a urlEncode(); directly from the above link, why do I have this extra ingredient?

Comment: By `urlEncode` you mean PHP [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Comment: So please, show us the code that produces such a result.

Comment: ... including the part that assigns `$encodedurl`...

Comment: ... and `$getURL` too! We need to whole chain of assignments to debug the problem.

Comment: So.... What's with the porn site?

Comment: my bad for using xxx, instead of domain, it's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%0A%3Cbr%3E is encoded version of `<br>`, so I suspect you have a line break in the original data, even though you don't see it. Try doing a trim() for it before you use it.

If you use urlencode of PHP to `http://www.xxx.com/retro-briefcase-messenger-bag-3380` you won't get such extra items, so you have to have it in the original data. I would presume you have line break going through htmlentities and then urlencode after that.

Only other possibility I can think of is that curl api adds a line break in there. You could verify that with hardcoded test url.

Comment: While correct (the OP noted it too), this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo umm... OP noted "which i believe represent a tag.", which doesn't sound like the same at all?

Comment: But yours is not an answer anyways? I will not downvote because it's not incorrect, still it is not an answer.

Comment: Well, I think it does. "you have that extra data because your original data has a line break in it". But I added some information now.

Comment: I just hardcode tested it , this <br> is hapening to all links hmm just curious how come php added it there isnt anythign between my code and encode